# How do I save Summernote text into drive using google drive API

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-drive-api, summernote

I have to post the text that the user of my page types on the Summernote editor, and save it to Google Drive. I used the google drive button that is mentioned at https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive, and I am having a problem saving the text to Drive. I am mainly confused by the data-src attribute of the g-savetodrive class. Here is a link to my code in HTML Editey.

I need to save all of the text in the USER'S GOOGLE DRIVE.

Link:   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1erEx9-MHNjosmtb4XmVRVXnceljUqRyN

Link to Instructions: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a90_kypUXyHig8B4lVFj728sY-AT15Vx/view

Take note that If you do not already have HTML Editey in your apps, you will have to connect in and accept its permissions before you can view this document with its result. If not, the code is still going to show up.

Thanks in advance,

Tommy John